# Which STM32 development board is suitable for a beginner?

Tags: stm32, development-tools, st

I am trying to learn STM32 programming. My goal is make my own embedded system using STM32 chip on separate PCB.

There are several development board in ST. What is the most suitable one for a beginner?

How about STM32F4 Discovery development board?

Your opinions are greatly appreciated.

*(This is about product recommendation, However this product is learning tool. I think I'm not violating rules)*

Comment: Evaluate the available software examples and related guidance for the board and its MCU sub-family before you pick it (or just buy several of the cheap ones).  Also consider which family best matches your application as changing horses can take a fair amount of work.  Most on-board extras beyond buttons and LEDs like microphones, accelerometers, etc on ST's own boards are put there are much to market a particular product as anything, and may not be the best choice for such a role in a DIY project.

Answer (score 1):

I am also a starter and have been using STM32F407VG-DISCOVERY board over 2 months and it has almost evetything a starter may need. But in my location discovery boards were more expensive than Nucleo boards. I guess a Nucleo board also does the job. However, discovery boards has 4 user LEDs while Nucleo has 1 or 2.

The maximum clock frequency is not a very important issue, just avoid buying a board based on a mcu less than 32kB flash memory. That is because when using stm32cubeide and its automatically created projects, the required flash size was almost 27 28 kB for simple projects.

Comment: @muyustn Thanks for your ansawer. Can you please tell me what are software tools that you are using? IDE, Compiler .....

Comment: I am using STM32CubeIDE which is a combination of old Atollic TrueStudio, which ST bought, and STM32CubeMX. This way, you can easily configure the pinout or clock settings and then jump into the coding part. However, it is useful to have also a Keil installed since sometimes the projects I found in the web are generated by Keil.

Comment: @user_fs10 I noticed I did not notify you.

Comment: If a simple project is requiring 27 KB of flash, then most likely the linker is misconfigured and not dropping unused sections.